# Groupby elements in a list of lists using strings from another list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have the following list of lists

```
listA = [
    ["4YBB|1|AA|A|262", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "tSH", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|C|264", "ntSH", 'empty', "5BPh", 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|G|259", "4YBB|1|AA|C|267", "cWW", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4WOI|1|DA|A|262", "4WOI|1|DA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4WOI|1|DA|C|264", "4WOI|1|DA|G|265", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty']
    ]
```

I would like to group these based on identifiers from another list and they must be ordered the same way as the elements in the identifiers list:

```
identifiers = ["4YBB|1|AA", "4WOI|1|DA"]
```

As you can see, the identifiers are subset of the string element 1 and 2 of the inner list. The identifiers will always be the same for element 1 and 2 of the inner list. The desired output is as follows:

```
desiredoutput = [
              [
                ["4YBB|1|AA|A|262", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'], 
                ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "tSH", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'], 
                ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|C|264", "ntSH", 'empty', "5BPh", 'empty'], 
                ["4YBB|1|AA|G|259", "4YBB|1|AA|C|267", "cWW", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
              ],
              [ 
                ["4WOI|1|DA|A|262", "4WOI|1|DA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'], 
                ["4WOI|1|DA|C|264", "4WOI|1|DA|G|265", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty']
              ]
            ]
```

How can I achieve this using the itertools `groupby` method or any other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `collections` module.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

listA = [
    ["4YBB|1|AA|A|262", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "tSH", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|C|264", "ntSH", 'empty', "5BPh", 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|G|259", "4YBB|1|AA|C|267", "cWW", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4WOI|1|DA|A|262", "4WOI|1|DA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4WOI|1|DA|C|264", "4WOI|1|DA|G|265", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty']
    ]
identifiers = ["4YBB|1|AA", "4WOI|1|DA"]
result = defaultdict(list)

for i in listA:
    key = i[0].rsplit('|', 2)[0]               #Get Key
    if key in identifiers:                     #Check in identifiers 
        result[key].append(i)                  #Group

result = OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda x: identifiers.index(x[0]))) #Sort base on identifiers 
print(result.values())
```

**Output:**

```
[[['4YBB|1|AA|A|262', '4YBB|1|AA|A|263', 'empty', 's35', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['4YBB|1|AA|U|261', '4YBB|1|AA|A|263', 'tSH', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['4YBB|1|AA|U|261', '4YBB|1|AA|C|264', 'ntSH', 'empty', '5BPh', 'empty'],
  ['4YBB|1|AA|G|259', '4YBB|1|AA|C|267', 'cWW', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty']],
 [['4WOI|1|DA|A|262', '4WOI|1|DA|A|263', 'empty', 's35', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['4WOI|1|DA|C|264', '4WOI|1|DA|G|265', 'empty', 's35', 'empty', 'empty']]]
```

---

Just an FYI. Using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

listA = [
    ["4YBB|1|AA|A|262", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "tSH", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|C|264", "ntSH", 'empty', "5BPh", 'empty'], 
    ["4YBB|1|AA|G|259", "4YBB|1|AA|C|267", "cWW", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4WOI|1|DA|A|262", "4WOI|1|DA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'], 
    ["4WOI|1|DA|C|264", "4WOI|1|DA|G|265", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty']
    ]
identifiers = ["4YBB|1|AA", "4WOI|1|DA"]

result = [list(value) for k, value in groupby(sorted(listA, key=lambda x: x[0].rsplit('|', 2)[0]), lambda x: x[0].rsplit('|', 2)[0]) if k in identifiers]
print(result)
```

Comment: ```"|".join(i[0].split("|")[:-2])``` can be changed to ```i[0].rsplit('|', 2)[0]```

Comment: @rakesh This works great but I need it to be ordered in the same way as the elements in the identifiers. I'll edit my question. So '4YBB' needs to come first before '4WOI'. How can I get them ordered in the same way?

Comment: Use `result = OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda x: identifiers.index(x[0])))
print(result.values())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it :

```
output = []
inter = []
prev_id = listA[0][0]
for element in listA:
    if element[0]==prev_id:
        inter.append(element)
    else:
        output.append(inter)
        prev_id = element[0]
        inter=[element]
```

Output :

```
[[['4YBB|1|AA|A|262', '4YBB|1|AA|A|263', 'empty', 's35', 'empty', 'empty']],
 [['4YBB|1|AA|U|261', '4YBB|1|AA|A|263', 'tSH', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['4YBB|1|AA|U|261', '4YBB|1|AA|C|264', 'ntSH', 'empty', '5BPh', 'empty']],
 [['4YBB|1|AA|G|259', '4YBB|1|AA|C|267', 'cWW', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty']],
 [['4WOI|1|DA|A|262', '4WOI|1|DA|A|263', 'empty', 's35', 'empty', 'empty']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As *the identifiers will always be the same for element 1 and 2 of the inner list.* - we can group on the needed slices with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

listA = [
    ["4YBB|1|AA|A|262", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'],
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "tSH", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|C|264", "ntSH", 'empty', "5BPh", 'empty'],
    ["4YBB|1|AA|G|259", "4YBB|1|AA|C|267", "cWW", 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
    ["4WOI|1|DA|A|262", "4WOI|1|DA|A|263", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty'],
    ["4WOI|1|DA|C|264", "4WOI|1|DA|G|265", 'empty', "s35", 'empty', 'empty']
    ]

groups = defaultdict(list)
for sub_l in listA:
    groups[sub_l[0][:10]].append(sub_l)

result = list(groups.values())
pprint.pprint(result)
```

The output:

```
[[['4YBB|1|AA|A|262', '4YBB|1|AA|A|263', 'empty', 's35', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['4YBB|1|AA|U|261', '4YBB|1|AA|A|263', 'tSH', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['4YBB|1|AA|U|261', '4YBB|1|AA|C|264', 'ntSH', 'empty', '5BPh', 'empty'],
  ['4YBB|1|AA|G|259', '4YBB|1|AA|C|267', 'cWW', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty']],
 [['4WOI|1|DA|A|262', '4WOI|1|DA|A|263', 'empty', 's35', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['4WOI|1|DA|C|264', '4WOI|1|DA|G|265', 'empty', 's35', 'empty', 'empty']]]
```